# How to pass refresh token of a third party IDP to the application via Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I’m working on an application which can read files of a given OneDrive account.

We use Azure AD B2C as the identity provider. Users can login to the application using their Microsoft account. For that we have [enabled Microsoft as an Identity Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account) in my AAD B2C tenant.

When a given user is login using their Microsoft account, application should be able to get both `access_token` and `refresh_token` which enables us to communicate with MS Graph API, in order to fetch file details.

Using custom polices we were able to fetch `access_token`. However, we cannot fetch the `refresh_token`.

This is how `ClaimsSchema` is defined in TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml :

```
<ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="ms_access_token">
        <DisplayName>MS access token</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
          <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:access_token}" />
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:access_token}" />
        </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <UserHelpText>access token form 3rd party MS AD.</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="ms_refresh_token">
        <DisplayName>MS Refresh token</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
          <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:refresh_token}" />
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:refresh_token}" />
        </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <UserHelpText>refresh token form 3rd party MS AD.</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
</ClaimsSchema>
```

Also in the same file, under the `TechnicalProfile` of Microsoft login, following `OutputClaims` node is added (some child nodes are removed for clarity):

```
<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ms_access_token" DefaultValue=""  />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ms_refresh_token" DefaultValue=""  />
</OutputClaims>
```

Then under the relevant `RelyingParty` node following `OutputClaims` node is added (some child nodes are removed for clarity):

```
<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ms_access_token" PartnerClaimType="ms_idp_access_token"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ms_refresh_token" PartnerClaimType="ms_idp_refresh_token"/>
</OutputClaims>
```

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#oauth2) there is no claim resolver for `refresh_token`.

Any suggestion to get this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to get this resolved by the help from a Microsoft employee in [MS forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/77296/how-to-pass-refresh-token-of-a-third-party-idp-to.html).

As of now, Azure AD B2C doesn't support this with OIDC providers. Therefore we have to enable Microsoft as an OAuth2 Identity Provider, instead of OIDC. For that we have to define a ClaimProvider like this:

```
  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <Domain>live.com</Domain>
      <DisplayName>Microsoft Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="MSA-OAuth">
          <DisplayName>Microsoft Account</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="OAuth2"/>
          <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf</Item>
            <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointAccessTokenName">access_token</Item>
            <Item Key="BearerTokenTransmissionMethod">AuthorizationHeader</Item>
            <Item Key="client_id"><!-- your client id --></Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">openid profile email offline_access files.read</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SampathAdCustomPolicyAppKey"/>
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="live.com" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="id"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ms_access_token" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:access_token}"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ms_refresh_token" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:refresh_token}"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

Comment: Great I will have to get around to trying that

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way you could do this would be via a custom api, that uses a password flow to authenticate the user. You can then return the refresh_token, access_token etc back from the API. I've not been able to figure any other way to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Did you mean: **Resource owner password credentials (ROPC)** flow ? If that is the case, according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?#ropc-flow-notes), it supports local accounts only. With that, users can’t sign in with federated identity providers.

Comment: Yep, sorry been moving a server this morning so not fully concentrating. I'm sure that I have seen something about doing it that way. I was looking for the say thing about getting the refresh_token. However, in the end decided that the loops were not worth it and we may go along the Authorise app method at a later date

Comment: I was able to get this worked. Please refer my answer. That might helps, in your use case as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the **{oauth2:refresh_token}** claims resolver returns a JSON string such as:

```
{
  "r": "<refresh_token>",
  "d": "live.com"
}
```

You can read the **r** property from this JSON string as follows.

1. Create [a **GetClaimFromJson** claims transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/json-transformations#getclaimfromjson):

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="GetRefreshTokenFromRefreshTokenResult" TransformationMethod="GetClaimFromJson">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ms_refresh_token" TransformationClaimType="inputJson" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="claimToExtract" DataType="string" Value="r" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ms_refresh_token" TransformationClaimType="extractedClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

2. Invoke this claims transformation from the **MSA-OAuth** technical profile as an output claims transformation:

```xml
<OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
  <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
  <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
  <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
  <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetRefreshTokenFromRefreshTokenResult" />
</OutputClaimsTransformations>
```